# Smooth version of Tietze extension theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Thanks to the properties of mollifications, it is very easy to prove Urysohn's lemma in the euclidean space with the big plus that the constructed function is smooth.

I was wondering if something of the kind could be achieved with Tietze extension theorem in the euclidean setting (i.e, can we always find smooth extensions of smooth functions in a closed set of the euclidean space?)

The proof of Tietze's theorem runs by constructing iteratively a family of functions with the aid of Urysohn's lemma. This family extends the original function and converges uniformly.

This is very nice, but I if I try to replicate the proof, I have no way to prove the uniform convergence of the derivatives, so I guess that if the theorem is true it will not follow these lines.

Thanks

Comment: See Fabio's question and answer "[Extension of continuous and smooth functions](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222647/extension-of-continuous-and-smooth-functions)" from MO.

Comment: [Linked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291860/a-counterexample-for-a-smoth-version-of-tietze-extension-theorem).

Comment: The answer depends on your definition of smoothness on compact sets. **Whitney's extension theorem** is about a notion of smoothness which allows smooth extensions of **all** smooth functions. On the other hand, there is the following classical example: Let $K=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: |y|\ge e^{-1/x}$ if $x>0\}$ and $f(x,y)=e^{-1/2x}$ if $x,y>0$ and $=0$ else. Then $f$ does not have an extension to a $C^1$-function on $\mathbb R^2$ because it is not Lipschitz continuous near $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1964-015-04/S0002-9939-1964-0165392-8/S0002-9939-1964-0165392-8.pdf

for a short note on extending smooth functions from the halfspace to euclidean space.  I originally got this reference from a stackexchange question which I am unable to find anymore.