# Can I extend a $C^1$ function?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, topological-vector-spaces

I have a compact subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and a $C^1$ function; $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $B\supseteq A$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Can I find a $C^1$ function $\tilde{f}:B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\tilde{f}|_A\equiv f$? If it is not possible, what is a good counter-example?

I feel like the answer should be that it is possible, but from what I've read online I'm not so sure. I saw that Whitney's approximation theorem might give me something similar to what I need, but I am a little confused by the notions of differentiability used (I was looking at these [lecture notes](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/Lecture%20notes%20-%20Extensions%20of%20functions.pdf) for instance and can't quite tell if Chapter 2 is saying I need extra conditions or not).

Comment: For $\mathcal C^0$, this is [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem). See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291860/a-counterexample-for-a-smoth-version-of-tietze-extension-theorem).

Comment: hmm, I'm a little confused on whether that question is discussing $C^\infty$ or $C^1$; Are you suggesting applying Tietsze extension theorem to the gradient operator?

Comment: What is the definition of $C^1$ for functions on arbitrary compact subsets?

Comment: Ah, okay, yes I take your point. If $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ is compact and $a \in U$, a map $F: U \rightarrow W$ is said to be $C^1$ at $\boldsymbol{a}$ if there exists a continuous linear map $L: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow W$ such that
$$
\lim _{v \rightarrow 0} \frac{|F(a+v)-F(a)-L v|}{|v|}=0 .
$$

Comment: How are you defining that limit unless $F$ is defined in some open disk around the point $a$ (and is thus at least *defined* in an open neighborhood containing $U$)? Some of the limit paths wouldn't exist; are you just considering paths coming from inside $D$, eg an analogue of a one-sided derivative? I would think you would at least want to start by continuously extending $F$ to an open set.

Comment: I was considering only the paths inside $D$; is this definition problematic?

Comment: Your definition is quite unusual, since what you call the definition of being **continuously differentiable** is usually the definition of "differentiable". Moreover, if the point a is "somewhat isolated" in U, then your limit might not be well defined, or your operator L might not be unique

Comment: "Continuously differentiable" means that the derivative is continuous as a function of the point $a$ where the derivative is being taken, not that the linear map which is the derivative value is continuous (a definition that would be pointless in finite dimensions, as all linear maps between finite-dimensional topological vector spaces are continuous). And taking of limits is only possible at accumulation points of the domain. So "$f$ is $C^1$ on $A$" is not even definable if $A$ has isolated points.

Comment: Thank you for these comments; I am a little confused and realise there is something fundamental I misunderstand about defining differentiation on compact sets. To avoid this going too far away from the question, I have tried to summarise my confusion in a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689539/what-does-c10-1-mean